# Trim string from left and from right

Tags: php, trim

How can I trim 5 characters from a string from left and right side. e.g.

```
4k2l3k4jc9l3kancie9
```

What should be trimmed and kept are:

```
4k2l3      k4jc9l3ka     ncie9
  ^            ^           ^
remove        keep       remove
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$string = substr($string, 5, -5);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = substr($string, 5, -5);//from left
$string = substr($string, 0, 5);//from right
```